# Error on Python Selenium (find_element_by_xpath)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to write a list of code to automate my daily file downloading process. I am using Python Selenium for this. However, I am having trouble to locate one of the clicks.

HTMI Code as below:

```
<div class="card dark-blue"> <h3 data-mh="title-research" style="height: 52px;">Rated Range Prices (LT)</h3> <h4 class="disp_date">26-Jan-2021 17:47:58</h4> <div class="divider"></div> <a href="javascript:seemore('F10002');" value="F10002" class="link">See More »</a> </div>
```

Here is my code:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:seemore('F10002');']")
```

The error msg:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@href='javascript:seemore('F10002');'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@href='javascript:seemore('F10002');']' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
```

Can anyone please enlighten me on this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element <kbd>See More »</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.card.dark-blue a.link[href*='seemore']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card dark-blue']//a[@class='link' and starts-with(., 'See More')]")
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate the **clickable** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.card.dark-blue a.link[href*='seemore']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card dark-blue']//a[@class='link' and starts-with(., 'See More')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You're using single quotes pair inside another single quotes pair...

Try

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//a[@href="javascript:seemore('F10002');"]''')
```

Comment: Thanks. The syntax is correct now. However, it is still unable to locate element. 

HTMI Code as below:
<div class="card dark-blue">
                    <h3 data-mh="title-research" style="height: 52px;">Rated Range Prices (LT)</h3>
                    <h4 class="disp_date">26-Jan-2021 17:47:58</h4>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                                        <a href="javascript:seemore('F10002');" value="F10002" class="link">See More »</a>
                                    </div>

Comment: @EdwinSoon check whether link located inside an iframe or you might need to [wait for element to be clickable](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)